# Randomize and shuffling a string without using stringbuilder or power tools

Tags: java, string, for-loop, shuffle

I want to shuffle a string without using any arrays, `StringBuilder`, or power tools (packages or methods that do the work for you) and using `Math.random()`.

My code below works but I don't like it because I can't use string builder or `.append()`. Could someone help me and fix it?

```java
public class loopPrr
{
  static String shuffle(int a) {
       
    String s = "BaaBooDaaDoo";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(a); 
  
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) { 
      int r = (int)(s.length() * Math.random()); 
  
      sb.append(s.charAt(r)); 
    } 
  
    return sb.toString();         
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to shuffle existing String or to generate a new randomized String of length `a` containing characters from the hardcoded pattern?

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you can simply use String:

```
static String shuffle(int a) {
    String s = "BaaBooDaaDoo";

    String sb = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        int r = (int) (s.length() * Math.random());

        sb += s.charAt(r);
    }

    return sb;
}
```

I would suggest changing the name of "sb" variable to avoid misunderstanding though.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to shuffle a string by applying [Fisher--Yates algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) to the character array of the input string.

The algorithm basically consists in swapping the characters at randomized indexes as shown below.

```java
static String shuffle(String str) {
    char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
    for (int i = str.length() - 1; i > 0 ; i--) { // starting from the last character
        int x = (int)(i * Math.random()); // next index is in range [0...i-1]
        char t = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[x];
        arr[x] = t;
    }
    return new String(arr);
}
```

If a randomized String of length `a` from the predefined alphabet needs to be generated, the following method can be implemented based on previous implementation for String to guarantee that all characters of the alphabet are used at least once if `a >= alphabet.length`:

```java
private static final String LETTERS = "AaBbCcDdEe";

static String shuffle(int a) {
    if (a <= 0) {
        return "";
    }
    if (a < LETTERS.length()) {
        char[] res = new char[a];
        for (int i = 0, x = LETTERS.length(); x > 0 && i < a; i++, x--) {
            res[i] = LETTERS.charAt((int)(Math.random() * x));
        }
        return new String(res);
    }
    return shuffle(shuffle(LETTERS) + shuffle(a - LETTERS.length()));
}
```